# Why doesn't MySQL give me a password at the end of my install process?

Tags: mysql, installation

I've seen youtube videos where coders get a temporary password at the end of the installation process which is necessary for connecting to a certain database on PopSql (I want to connect to Mike Dane's). Can't connect to the database without the password.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem and solved it, I'm using a mac (version 10.15.2 Catalina) . I had to download an older version of MySQL (had to use 5.7.29), the newest version (8.0.19) wouldn't give me the password. Here is a link to the newer version of MySQL, WHEN YOU GET TO THIS PAGE YOU MUST CLICK 'Looking for previous GA versions?', then download version 5.7.29. For some reason linking it directly doesn't work.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/